# VB.net linq left join where null or 0

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do a left join and pull records where the join is null, or the join works, but the column paid is 0. This is the sql I'm trying to recreate

```
SELECT * 
    FROM JobsCompleted
    LEFT JOIN SqWar ON JobsCompleted.JobFk = SqWar.JobFk
    WHERE SqWar.SqWarId IS NULL OR SqWar.Paid = 0
```

This is what I have so far in linq

```
'not sure here how I do if the join is null, or joins, but paid is 0
            Dim jobIds = (From jc In db.JobsCompleteds
                          Group Join sqw In db.SqWars On sqw.JobFk Equals jc.JobFk Into SqGroup = Group
                          Where jc.DateCompleted >= fromInput.SelectedDate And jc.DateCompleted <= toInput.SelectedDate And
                              SqGroup Is Nothing) 'not sure here how I do if it's null or paid = 0
```

Comment: FIrst of all: use navigation properties, no joins.

Comment: Thanks for your super helpful answer. The database I'm working in doesn't have any FK constraints set up so i can't use those, which is why I didn't ask how to use navigation properties to select the data.

Comment: You can still set up associations in the mapped model.

Comment: Yup, I'll probably just redesign the entire database and migrate the application to node while I'm at it.

Comment: Associations in the mapped model are *without* changing the database. Anyway, take it or leave it.

Comment: Sarcasm does not fit the SO directive "Be Nice"

Comment: Your SQL seems to have very little relationship to your LINQ query - can you show your actual SQL or the correct query?

Comment: If it seems to have nothing to do with my linq query, then I'm just writing something wrong in the linq. I basically want to recreate that sql in linq, where I'm left joining, and then either getting a record if the left join is null, or the left join works, but paid is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `Group Join`, if you want a SQL `LEFT JOIN`, especially since you are wanting to test a field from the right hand side, you need to use a second `From` clause with `DefaultIfEmpty`:

```
Dim jobIds = From jc In db.JobsCompleteds
             Group Join sqw In db.SqWars On sqw.JobFk Equals jc.JobFk Into Group
             From sqw In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
             Where sqw Is Nothing Or sqw.Paid = 0
             Select New With { jc, sqw }
```

Note that LINQ doesn't have a direct equivalent to SQL `SELECT *` so I returned an anonymous object with sub-objects. If you wanted the result to be flattened, you would have to explicitly list all fields.

If you wanted to process the join groups you could also filter each group by your criteria:

```
Dim jobIdsG = From jc In db.JobsCompleteds
              Group Join sqw In db.SqWars On sqw.JobFk Equals jc.JobFk Into Group
              Select New With {jc, .sqGroup = Group.Where(Function(sq) sq.Paid = 0)}
```